# rounding a variable to 2 dp whilst adding a 0 to the end og 1dp values

Tags: python

I've written a for loop code to print out different values depending on the value coming from a list

```
percentages = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

It rounding the answer given by the calculation below to 2 dp but on one of the values I receive (3.5) it doesn't round to 3.50

```
tax_price = round(x/(100/percent[i]), 2)
```

x being the user's input

How would i go about making it post 3.50 rather than 3.5

Comment: You can't put a zero at the end unless you use a string.

Comment: it is being changed into a string later on in the code for being printed

Comment: What about `'{0:.2f}'.format(3.5)`

Comment: that would only work for the 3.5 value though wouldn't it. the user can input any number they want to get an output

Comment: And `'{0:.2f}'.format(tax_price)`?

Comment: yeah ill try that thanks

Comment: well its to 2 dp so in some cases i want the .5 or .1 to be .50 or .10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `format` for that. From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> Preceding the *width* field by a zero (`'0'`) character enables sign-aware
>   zero-padding for numeric types. This is equivalent to a *fill* character
>   of `'0'` with an *alignment* type of `'='`.

```
print('{0:.2f}'.format(tax_price))
```

Example:

```
print('{0:.2f}'.format(3.5))
3.50
```

Comment: I actually had that I copied the wrong version, sorry. It still doesn't fix the 3.5 though

Answer (score 0):

How about this logic ?

```
percentage = [5,10,15,20]
x = int(input("User input"))
result = []
for i in percentage:
    tax_price = x/(100/i)
    result.append('{:.2f}'.format(tax_price))

print(result)
```

Comment: thats pretty much what i already had, i only posted the lines i needed help with